# Unrouted Nets Error in Altium 18!

Tags: altium, routing

So, I use Altium 18 and I was checking the Board information for my PCB.

Under Nets, it showed total of 24 Nets and 0 Unrouted Nets. During my checks I found one of the nets was unconnected, yet the Board Information showed "zero" Unrouted nets.

So, I connected the net and then disconnected it. Only this time upon disconnecting the net, the count of Unrouted nets became '1'. Has anyone encountered anything like this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you run your DRC? That will show you which nets are unrouted. I would not rely on the "Board information" to tell you how many nets are unrouted.

Comment: @DerStrom8: No, I didn't but I have learnt to not rely on board information now. Only trust DRC